# Windows wget UTF-8 names

Tags: batch-file, utf-8, ftp, wget

i'm trying to create a batch script that connects to my ftp server (windows server 2012 R2) and downloads a tree of directories.

I'm using GNUWin32's wget with the following commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" --ftp-user=foo --ftp-password=foo ftp://ip.ip.ip.ip/directory/directory --level=0 --no-glob --continue --timestamping --tries=0 --recursive
```

The problem is that even if on my ftp server and on the database (postgres) everything is saved as UTF-8 and displayed correctly. when i download the directory tree with wget the things downloaded don't have the correct encoding (E.G. ü becomes Ã¼)

Is there a way to make it so the downloaded folders will have the same name as the ones on the server? I've been trying to achieve this for 3 days with no avail

P.S. I've tried downloading the files with Filezilla forcing UTF-8 and they end up having the correct name but i need a solution that will work unattended and filezilla doesn't support that from what i understood

Comment: Maybe that [changing current `cmd` code page to _UTF-8_](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) could help: place `chcp 65001` command somewhere before running `wget`.

Comment: already tried, the characters in the terminal output are different (still not correct) but the filenames are the same as the ones that i get without `chcp 65001`

Comment: [wget unicode filename errors](//stackoverflow.com/a/22013384) Try WinSCP or other FTP client.

Comment: @JosefZ i fixed it by forcing the ASCII conversion on Wget and then renaming the files with the powershell to convert them back to UTF-8. Thanks anyway for the help :)

Comment: Hi, do you mind giving an example of the commands you used?

Comment: @tfonias74 i added an answer with what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, i used the following wget command

```
wget --ftp-user=%ADMIN% --ftp-password=%PASSWORD% ftp://%IP% --level=0 --no-glob --continue --tries=0 --recursive --restrict-file-names=ascii
```

to donload the files forcing the ASCII encoding and then this powershell script to convert them back to UTF-8

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;

# Get the filenames and order them to have the files first
$data = get-childitem %PATH_TO_FOLDER% -recurse | Sort-Object FullName -descending;

# Cycle every file
ForEach($dat in $data){
 # Get the decoded UTF-8 name
 $decoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($dat.name);

 # Rename the file if the decoded name is different than the current one
 if ($dat.name -ne $decoded){ren $dat.FullName $decoded}

}
```

It could probably be made better but i don't know enough about powershell to do so and this works nicely for my needs anyway